# Use Brahmagupta’s formula to show that, for a fixed given perimeter p, the cyclic quadrilateral with largest area is equilateral

Tags: calculus

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I know how to prove if something is equilateral, but each time I try, I seem to get a different answer. Please help!

A link to the image is included below.

[My source of stress :P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR1M2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b,c,d$ denote the side lengths of the quadrilateral and let $s=(a+b+c+d)/2$ denote half the perimeter. Brahmagupta's formula says that the area of the quadrilateral is
$$
\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}.
$$
By the AM-GM inequality,
$$
\sqrt[4]{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}\leq \frac{(s-a)+(s-b)+(s-c)+(s-d)}{4}=\frac{a+b+c+d}{4},
$$
with equality when $a=b=c=d$.

Comment: Is the last denominator not $\frac43$? Not that this would change the essence of the solution.

Comment: The denominator is correct, since the numerator on the right hand side is $4s-a-b-c-d=2(a+b+c+d)-a-b-c-d=a+b+c+d$.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed $p$ and $s$. The $\frac12$ thing is important.

Comment: What a quick reply! Thank you for sharing your solution with me. Simple and clear, that's how I like it.